# how to asynchronous validation in blazor srver?

Tags: asynchronous, blazor-server-side, fluentvalidation, blazor-editform

In Blazor Server i use `<FluentValidationValidator />` to validate the form
also i use MustAsync in my validator
But when the form is submitted, Validation is executed, but the program does not wait for the end of Validation and the execution of the program continues.

```
<EditForm Model="Model">
    <FluentValidationValidator Validator="FormValidator"></FluentValidationValidator>
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
    ...
</EditForm>
```

and my validator

```
public class FormValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    RuleFor(e => e.Name)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
            .MustAsync(BeUniqNameAsync).WithMessage("Name Must Be Unique");
}
```

Comment: Blazor does not currently support async validation. There are Blazored.FluentValidation issues explaining this problem: https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation/issues/31